# iOS - properly animate between two UIViews using CATransition

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition, catransition

I have a UIView already on my screen and i wish to "slide in" a new UIView from one of the four directions(left, right, up, down) depending on what kind of swipegesture that i detect. Getting the swipegesture info is already done and not a problem but now, lets say if I swipe to the left then i want another UIView instance to "slide in" from the right.

Specifically, as the new UIView is sliding in from the right, the old UIView starts to slide out of view sliding to the left until it is out of the view completely. In other words, i would like to have the effect taht you can see both UIViews during the animation until the original UIView is no longer visible. The same type of effect can be seen on your iPad, for example, as you are on your home screen and you swipe to the left - which slides in another screen of app icons from the right as your home screen slides out of view to the left. The only caveat that I would like to achieve would be that you cannot stop the transition midstream.

Anyway here is the code that i have so far - I think that i am close but would like to get some help on perhaps finishing what i need to accomplish here:

```
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    newView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, TileView.frame.size.width, TileView.frame.size.height);
    [TileView addSubView:view];
    CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
    [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
    [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [transitionAnimation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
```

The UIView TileView is a subview of my viewController. Is there any other setting up to do for newView so that everything matches as far as screen placement? I *think* that the KCATransitionPush is the type of animation I am looking for but not 100% sure.

Any help to what I am missing here would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try to set these two property also....

```
transitionAnimation.fromValue=[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
transitionAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(excursion, 0.0, 0.0)];
```